# NSNetService publishes, but didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream... is never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, nsnetservice

I've been trying to make a simple app on iOS that will receive a message, and then perform an action based on that message (at the moment I just want to show it via `NSLog`). I can connect to the service, but the service never seems to receive anything. Here's my .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>

@interface PalServiceController : NSObject <NSNetServiceDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNetService *ns;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOutputStream *ostream;

- (void)start;
+ (int)getPort;
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode;

@end
```

and my .m:

```
#import "PalServiceController.h"

@implementation PalServiceController

- (void)start
{
    // Start a net service
    int port = [PalServiceController getPort];
    NSLog(@"Opening on port %i", port);
    self.ns = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@""
                                              type:@"_TestingProtocol._tcp."
                                              name:@"Test Name For iPhone"
                                              port:port];
    if (self.ns) {
        [self.ns setDelegate:self];
        [self.ns publish];
        self.ns.delegate = self;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error starting service");
    }

}

/*
 * Code from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11723158/657676
 */
+ (int) getPort
{
 ...   
}

- (void)netServiceWillResolve:(NSNetService *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Resolving");
}

- (void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:(NSNetService *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Resolved Address");
}

- (void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didNotPublish:(NSDictionary *)errorDict
{
    NSLog(@"Error publishing");
}

- (void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:(NSInputStream *)inputStream outputStream:(NSOutputStream *)outputStream
{
    NSLog(@"Got a connection! (server)");
    // Close self down
    [self.ns stopMonitoring];
    [self.ns stop];
}

- (void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didNotResolve:(NSDictionary *)errorDict
{
    NSLog(@"Error resolving");
}
- (void)netServiceDidPublish:(NSNetService *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Published server");
}

- (void)netServiceDidStop:(NSNetService *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Server stopped");
}

- (void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didUpdateTXTRecordData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Updated TXT Record");
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    NSLog(@"Event on server");
    switch(eventCode) {
        ...
    }
}

@end
```

This is called via:

```
self.controller = [[PalServiceController alloc] init];
[self.controller start];
```

When I use [Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/), I can see the service, and when I use either my own implementation of an `NSNetServiceBrowser` or the example from Bill Dudney([blog post](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/bonjour_network_server_for_iphone), [code](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/resource/NetworkingTesting.zip)), it seems to connect (i.e. my own implementation receives the `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` and `NSStreamEventOpenCompleted`events via `stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode`). However, none of the methods above get called on the server.

I'm still new to iOS, so I'm hoping that this is just some silly mistake that can be easily fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-[NSNetService publish]` simply publishes the service; you're responsible for creating a socket and listening on the port you give to the NSNetService initializer. You won't receive `netService:didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:outputStream:` because the NSNetService knows nothing about the socket.

If you want the NSNetService to manage the socket for you—and send `didAcceptConnection...`—use `-[NSNetService publishWithOptions:]`:

```
[self.ns publishWithOptions:NSNetServiceListenForConnections];
```

In this case, you need to make sure that the port with which you initialize the NSNetService is unused. Your `getPort` method never closes the socket (and leaks the CFSocketRef), so it will be in use when you publish the service, leading to an error.

I'd recommend that you remove `getPort` and, as Apple suggests in NSNetServices.h, "[s]pecify a port number of zero to use a random port."

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Doing this seems to do 2 interesting things: 1. It calls the `(void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didNotPublish:(NSDictionary *)errorDict` method, and then the `(void)netServiceDidPublish:(NSNetService *)sender` (that's called twice when just using `[self.ns publish]`, too. 2. It doesn't seem to be listening on the `local.` domain, and explicitly setting the domain to `local.` does the same, but with only 1 call to `netServiceDidPublish`, and doesn't seem to be published.  Any idea what could be causing this now?

Comment: Yes, that's right! I remember reading that somewhere and then thinking I can't do that for NSNetService, so thanks for pointing that out. All seems to be working now so thank you very much

Comment: It's worked for me. Unfortunately I have read this post after that I fixed this problem by himself